# How to parse simple XML with attribute using retrofit?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, retrofit

This my simple XML data
    `<Command><KeyClickResult status="OK"/></Command>`. I need to get the status of the response.

I've tried using both `@Element` as well as `@Text` if I use `"required = false"`

I am getting 200 response but if I use `"required = true"` then am getting the below exception

> "org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Empty value for
>   @org.simpleframework.xml.Text(data=false, empty=, required=true) on
>   field 'keyClickResult"

```
@Root(name = "Command", strict = false)
public class KeyCommandData {
    @Text(required = false)
    private String keyClickResult;
```

```
@Element(name = "KeyClickResult")
    private String keyClickResult;
```

I need to get the status of the response but currently, am getting an exception.

Comment: Firstly, `retrofit` has nothing to do with parsing. It only does the network requests. What are you using to parse XML?

Comment: Remove space between KeyClickResult and status. it is look like as <Command><KeyClickResultstatus="OK"/></Command> and used like this 
@Element(name = "KeyClickResultstatus")
    private String keyClickResult;

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thank you for your reply am using "retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0"

Comment: @GautamKushwaha no it's valid XML data to parse. Status is the attribute.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Can you help me to fix this problem? If I use **required false** then I get the success response when I try to use **KeyClickResult** to parse it gives the Exception which I said in the question.

Comment: @MohanK can you share your API or full XML demo?

Comment: @GautamKushwaha ```<Command><KeyClickResult status="OK"/></Command>``` this the full XML data to parse. It's just the status response with **status** attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code in your Model

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name = "Command")
public class Command {

    public KeyClickResult getTitle() {
        return keyClickResult;
    }

    @Element(name = "KeyClickResult")
    public KeyClickResult keyClickResult;

    static public class KeyClickResult {

        @Attribute(name = "status")
        public String status;

    }
}
```

and get response from :  `response.body().getTitle()`

Comment: Saved my day. Working perfectly:-)

Comment: I already upvoted but I am having less than 15 reputations so it's not displayed in public.